# Error missing template argument before . token linkedStackType.push(1)

Tags: c++, debugging, stack

Getting this error or a similar one everywhere in the code where the linkedStackType. is located. Not sure what is looking for. Error sounds look for something before the period as an argument. If somebody could clarify the error or explain what the argument should be I would appreciate it.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "linkedStack.h"   using namespace std;   bool isPrime(long num); 

int main() {
    linkedStackType<long> stack;
    long num;
    long temp;   //  long factor;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer greater than 1: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    while (num <= 1)
    {
        cout << "You must enter a positive integer greater than 1: " << endl;
        cin >> num;
    }

    cout << "The prime factoriztion of " << num << ": ";

    // ensure that "num" is prime

    // use "stack" to print the prime factors of "num" in descending order

    linkedStackType.push(1);

    if ((num % 2) == 0)         linkedStackType.push(2);

    for (temp = 3; temp < num; temp++)  {       if ((num % temp == 0) && (isPrime(temp)))       {           linkedStackType.push(temp);         }   }
    while (!linkedStackType.empty())    {       cout << linkedStackType.top() << " ";       linkedStackType.pop();  }

    return 0; }

bool isPrime(long num) {
      if (num <= 3) {
        return num > 1;
    } else if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 5; i * i <= num; i += 6) {
            if (num % i == 0 || num % (i + 2) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // write a function that returns whether "num" is prime }
```

linkedStack.h

```
//Header File: linkedStack.h

#ifndef H_StackType
#define H_StackType

#include <iostream> 
#include <cassert>

#include "stackADT.h"

using namespace std;

//Definition of the node
template <class Type>
struct nodeType
{
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};

template <class Type>
class linkedStackType: public stackADT<Type>
{
public:
    const linkedStackType<Type>& operator=
                              (const linkedStackType<Type>&);
      //Overload the assignment operator.

    bool isEmptyStack() const;
      //Function to determine whether the stack is empty.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is empty;
      //               otherwise returns false.

    bool isFullStack() const;
      //Function to determine whether the stack is full.
      //Postcondition: Returns false.

    void initializeStack();
      //Function to initialize the stack to an empty state. 
      //Postcondition: The stack elements are removed; 
      //               stackTop = nullptr;

    void push(const Type& newItem);
      //Function to add newItem to the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not full.
      //Postcondition: The stack is changed and newItem 
      //               is added to the top of the stack.

    Type top() const;
      //Function to return the top element of the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: If the stack is empty, the program 
      //               terminates; otherwise, the top 
      //               element of the stack is returned.

    void pop();
      //Function to remove the top element of the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: The stack is changed and the top 
      //               element is removed from the stack.

    linkedStackType(); 
      //Default constructor
      //Postcondition: stackTop = nullptr;

    linkedStackType(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack); 
      //Copy constructor

    ~linkedStackType();
      //Destructor
      //Postcondition: All the elements of the stack are 
      //               removed from the stack.

private:
    nodeType<Type> *stackTop; //pointer to the stack

    void copyStack(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack); 
      //Function to make a copy of otherStack.
      //Postcondition: A copy of otherStack is created and
      //               assigned to this stack.
};

    //Default constructor
template <class Type> 
linkedStackType<Type>::linkedStackType()
{
    stackTop = nullptr;
}

template <class Type>
bool linkedStackType<Type>::isEmptyStack() const
{
    return(stackTop == nullptr);
} //end isEmptyStack

template <class Type>
bool linkedStackType<Type>:: isFullStack() const
{
    return false;
} //end isFullStack

template <class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::initializeStack()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp; //pointer to delete the node

    while (stackTop != nullptr)    //while there are elements in 
                                //the stack
    {
        temp = stackTop;    //set temp to point to the 
                            //current node
        stackTop = stackTop->link;  //advance stackTop to the
                                    //next node
        delete temp;    //deallocate memory occupied by temp
    }
} //end initializeStack

template <class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::push(const Type& newElement)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;  //pointer to create the new node

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node

    newNode->info = newElement; //store newElement in the node
    newNode->link = stackTop; //insert newNode before stackTop
    stackTop = newNode;       //set stackTop to point to the 
                              //top node
} //end push

template <class Type>
Type linkedStackType<Type>::top() const
{
    assert(stackTop != nullptr); //if stack is empty,
                              //terminate the program
    return stackTop->info;    //return the top element 
}//end top

template <class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::pop()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;   //pointer to deallocate memory

    if (stackTop != nullptr)
    {
        temp = stackTop;  //set temp to point to the top node

        stackTop = stackTop->link;  //advance stackTop to the 
                                    //next node
        delete temp;    //delete the top node
    }
    else
        cout << "Cannot remove from an empty stack." << endl;
}//end pop

template <class Type> 
void linkedStackType<Type>::copyStack
                     (const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode, *current, *last;

    if (stackTop != nullptr) //if stack is nonempty, make it empty
        initializeStack();

    if (otherStack.stackTop == nullptr)
        stackTop = nullptr;
    else
    {
        current = otherStack.stackTop;  //set current to point
                                   //to the stack to be copied

            //copy the stackTop element of the stack 
        stackTop = new nodeType<Type>;  //create the node

        stackTop->info = current->info; //copy the info
        stackTop->link = nullptr;  //set the link field of the
                                //node to nullptr
        last = stackTop;        //set last to point to the node
        current = current->link;    //set current to point to
                                    //the next node

            //copy the remaining stack
        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
            newNode->info = current->info;
            newNode->link = nullptr;
            last->link = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            current = current->link;
        }//end while
    }//end else
} //end copyStack

    //copy constructor
template <class Type>   
linkedStackType<Type>::linkedStackType(
                      const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    stackTop = nullptr;
    copyStack(otherStack);
}//end copy constructor

    //destructor
template <class Type> 
linkedStackType<Type>::~linkedStackType()
{
    initializeStack();
}//end destructor

    //overloading the assignment operator
template <class Type>   
const linkedStackType<Type>& linkedStackType<Type>::operator=
                  (const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack)
{ 
    if (this != &otherStack) //avoid self-copy
        copyStack(otherStack);

    return *this; 
}//end operator=

#endif
```

stackADT.h

```
//Header file: stackADT.h

#ifndef H_StackADT
#define H_StackADT

template <class Type> 
class stackADT
{
public:
    virtual void initializeStack() = 0;
       //Method to initialize the stack to an empty state.
       //Postcondition: Stack is empty

    virtual bool isEmptyStack() const = 0;
      //Function to determine whether the stack is empty.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is empty,
      //               otherwise returns false.

    virtual bool isFullStack() const = 0;
      //Function to determine whether the stack is full.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is full,
      //               otherwise returns false.

    virtual void push(const Type& newItem) = 0;
      //Function to add newItem to the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not full.
      //Postcondition: The stack is changed and newItem 
      //               is added to the top of the stack.

    virtual Type top() const = 0;
      //Function to return the top element of the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: If the stack is empty, the program 
      //               terminates; otherwise, the top element
      //               of the stack is returned.

    virtual void pop() = 0;
      //Function to remove the top element of the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: The stack is changed and the top 
      //               element is removed from the stack.
};

#endif
```

Comment: `linkedStackType.push(1);` should be `stack.push(1)` as `linkedStackType` is the tempalte type. `stack` is the variable.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue.